# I get only app-release-unaligned.apk when I press generate signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, apk, build.gradle

I always get "app-release-unaligned.apk". I can't get "app-release.apk".
But before I've updated Android SDK, I can get both "app-release.apk" and "app-release-unaligned.apk" after pressing Build->Generate Signed Apk...

System Mac OS. Android Studio 1.5.1. Android SDK Tools 25.1.1. Android SDK Platform-tools 23.1. Android SDK Build-tools 23.0.3.

I found the similar problem on [Android Developer Tools Google Plus](https://plus.google.com/112427872611494847110/posts/SSBKK4zNGVZ)

**UPD1** I've used cmd to align my apk. Because I could not publish my application to google play. `zipalign -v 4 your_project_name-unaligned.apk your_project_name.apk` .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`app-release.apk` file is in the application folder.

Sometimes Android studio shows another directory where the unaligned file is.

in my case The `app-release.apk` was in `app/` folder not in `outputs/apk/`