# Android Studio 2.1 does not generate signed Apk after updating

Tags: android-studio, apk

Recently, I've updated my android studio from 1.3 to 2.1. After that, when I trying to create a signed apk from "Generate Signed APK" in build menu. Android studio seems to works fine and prompting for successful generating release file, but always there is not such apk file in selected output folder. Also, open directory from successful pop up message does not work.
I try creating new keystore for signing and reinstalling android studio as suggested in some posts, but there is no change on issue..

This is build.gradle file I am using:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.vcc4.homeui"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.6.2.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: it's not necessary to create signed APK in output folder. did you check whole root of project?

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36489393/2494799

Comment: Thanks @MounirElfassi and @ Amir for responses. I've searched in any possible folder to find signed apk but no results.. By the way, I tried to create a new project then copy paste all lines of code into new one and it solved the problem temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. And I found out that the generated apk was moved from the "app" folder to the "app/build/outputs/apk/" folder.

I do not know if it's a bug or a feature but it probably has something to do with "Automatically Sign Your APK", as this article https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#release-mode describes the folder mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today. I restarted Android Studio and that could have solved the issue -- in the meantime, I had issues with ProGuard etc. that started failing my build, so maybe some Gradle sync, project rebuild etc. also came in handy

But I have a sneaking suspicion this is to do with restarting maybe AS or even your machine. I ran into this same issue last time I was trying to build a signed APK and everytime this seems to take up a few of my hours....I need to figure this out too

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the apk generated will be in

```
{project-folder}/app/release/app-release.apk
```